# Hibernate not able to fetch based on mixed case quoted column

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have the following table in my oracle database :

```
CREATE TABLE "USERCREDENTIALS" (
"userID"                            VARCHAR2(40)        NOT NULL ,
"delFlag"                           VARCHAR2(1)          DEFAULT 'N',
PRIMARY KEY("userID") ) /
```

This creates the following table :

```
SQL> desc ORAUSER.USERCREDENTIALS
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 userID                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(40)
 delFlag                        VARCHAR2(1)
```

Now, I am trying to select from this table via hibernate.

The hibernate hbm.xml file contains the following entries:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="cxps.security.glossary.UserCredentials" table="`USERCREDENTIALS`" abstract="false">
        <id name="primaryKey" type="string" column="`userID`" length="40">
        </id>
        <property name="delFlag" type="string" column="`delFlag`" length="1" not-null="false" unique="false" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

note that backquotes are used to indicate that the column names are case sensitive.

Now I am trying to execute the query using hibernate, thus:

```
"FROM "+UserCredentials.class.getName()+" WHERE delFlag = 'N' and userID= '"+username+"'";
```

The query is printed as follows:

```
2014-02-21 15:52:58,986 ERROR [Search] THR(http-5000-exec-1): Error in executing query : FROM cxps.security.glossary.UserCredentials WHERE delFlag = 'N' and userID= 'USER_1'
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2545)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at mypackage.myClass.method(Filename.java:230)
```

The oracle error is :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "USERID": invalid identifier
```

Clearly, the column name is being upcased in oracle.
I understand that the backqotes in the hbm.xml file indicate that the mixed case should be used but that is not happening.

What is the way out?

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to wrong name `userID`, in hbm you have mentioned `primaryKey`

```
 <id name="primaryKey" type="string" column="`userID`" length="40">
             ↑
```

So, change the name to `userId`.

---

Please use [Query#setParameter(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) to set the parameter. Don't use string concatenation.

#### See also

- [Mapping declaration id](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
FROM "+UserCredentials.class.getName()+" WHERE delFlag = 'N' and primaryKey= '"+username+"'
```

Thus, use the Java attribute name `primaryKey` and not the DB attribute name `userID`. And yes, don't use string concatenation as this is a security whole.